# Android X library throwing error when compiling

Tags: android, kotlin, android-support-library, androidx

I'm getting this error when building my project in android studio 3.1.3

> Program type already present:
>   android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy
>   Message{kind=ERROR, text=Program type already present:
>   android.support.v4.app.INotificationSideChannel$Stub$Proxy,
>   sources=[Unknown source file], tool name=Optional.of(D8)}

I started migrating to **AndroidX** libraries here's `gradle.build`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.jimmy.bitcoinpriceindex"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

//    enable databinding
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }

//    add java 8 features support
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:runner:$versions.test"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:$versions.espresso"
    implementation"org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"


    // ViewModel and LiveData
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$versions.lifecycle"

    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$versions.support"

    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:$versions.constraint_layout"
    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$versions.glide"

    // work manager dependency
    implementation "android.arch.work:work-runtime:$versions.work"

    implementation ("com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$versions.retrofit"){
        // exclude Retrofit’s OkHttp dependency module and define your own module import
        exclude module: 'okhttp'
    }
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:$versions.retrofit"
    implementation "com.google.code.gson:gson:$versions.gson"

    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$versions.loggin_interceptor"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:$versions.okttp"

}


apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, revert back to your original state before migrating.
There is an inbuilt tool that converts your whole Android project to Androidx.
I am using Android studio 3.3.

Refactor > Migrate Apps to Androidx

Here is a copy how my depencencies in gradle look like after converting/migrating:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0-beta01'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-beta01'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha3'

    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:0.3.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0-beta01'

}
```

Comment: In android studio 3.1.3, that option is not available. I only have migrate app to appCompat..